# Programmatically add directive uib-typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I wish to create a directive that adds the **uib-typeahead** directive to itself.

Something like this:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myOptions', ['$interpolate', '$compile', '$parse', 
function($interpolate, $compile, $parse){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element){
            scope.options = ['aa', 'ab', 'ac'];
            element.attr('uib-typeahead', 'option in options');
        }
    };
}]);
```

I know this won't work, because the **'option in options'** is just a string. I have tried `$compile`, `$interpolate` and `$parse`, but without any luck. I'm probably just not using them correct.

The idea is that I should be able to add **my-directive** to an input element, and then the options are automatically put in the scope for the typeahead.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the desired behavior by specifying `template` and setting `replace: true` :

```
 .directive('myOptions', [
        function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                template: '<input type="text" uib-typeahead="state for state in states">',
                replace: true,
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska'];
                }
            };
        }])
```

Example

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')



    .directive('myOptions', ['$interpolate', '$compile', '$parse',
        function ($interpolate, $compile, $parse) {

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                template: '<input type="text" uib-typeahead="state for state in states">',
                replace: true,
                //require: ['ngModel', 'uibTypeahead'],
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];;
                }
            };
        }])

    .controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.selected = undefined;
       
    });
```

```html
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    
    <div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <h4>Example</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" my-options  ng-model="selected">
</div>
```